# Store dates using Eloquent/Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

What's a good way of storing a date in a Eloquent Model? I'm using PHP with Laravel framework.

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
  // I want a date field here... should it be:
  public $endTime = ?;
}
```

Should I use a integer timestamp which gets saved as an int? What's the behaviour if I use a Date object in a atributte and save that object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [migration](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations) then use `$table->timestamp('endTime')`, this will create a `timestamp` field by using `endTime` as it's name.

> By default, **Eloquent** will convert the **created_at**, **updated_at**, and
>   **deleted_at** columns to instances of **Carbon**, which provides an
>   assortment of helpful methods, and extends the native **PHP DateTime**
>   class. You may customize which fields are automatically mutated, and
>   even completely disable this mutation, by overriding the getDates
>   method of the model.

Add this method in your model:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'endTime');
}
```

`Laravel` will take care of these fields and by default each of these fields will be an instance of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) object. Read about [date mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#date-mutators). In this case all methods of `Carbon` could be used on these fields.